# A question from functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

[image] Can somebody help me out with this question step by step. I have just started Hilbert spaces and not too good in functional analysis. I know all the definitions and concepts but I cannot solve much questions when it comes to analysis. I have to do this question but I also want to understand what I have to do in this. Any helping hand is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of $\sigma_{e}$?

Comment: @T.A.E. It is the eigenspectrum of the operator $T$

Comment: @T.A.E. Can you help me with this-  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036490/functional-analysis-question-about-proving-j-phi-phi

Comment: @T.A.E. can you help me with [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040031/show-that-both-s-and-t-are-bounded?noredirect=1#comment2119387_1040031) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040035/show-sigmat-sigma-overlinet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For a complex Hilbert space, $T$ is normal iff $\|Tx\|=\|T^{\star}x\|$ for all $x$. This is due to the polarization identity, which is a useful algebraic tool:
   $$
                      (x,y) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^{n}\|x+i^{n}y\|^{2}.
   $$
   If $T$ is normal, then so is $T-\lambda I$ for any complex $\lambda$, with adjoint $T^{\star}-\overline{\lambda}I$. Therefore, if $T$ is normal, then $\|(T-\lambda I)x\|=\|(T^{\star}-\overline{\lambda}I)x\|$. So $Tx=\lambda x$ iff $T^{\star}x=\overline{\lambda}x$.
2. Standard trick: If $Tx=\lambda x$ and $Ty=\mu y$, then $T^{\star}y=\overline{\mu}y$ and
   $$
          (\lambda-\mu)(x,y) = (Tx,y)-(x,T^{\star}y)= (Tx,y)-(Tx,y)=0.
   $$
   Therefore, if $\lambda \ne \mu$, then $(x,y)=0$.
3. Assume the contrary and reach a contradiction. If $Tx_{n}=\lambda_{n}x_{n}$ where  $\{ x_{n} \}$ are unit vectors, $\{ \lambda_{n} \}$ are distinct and $|\lambda_{n}| \ge t > 0$, then (2) implies $\{ x_{n} \}$ is an orthonormal subset for which $\{ Tx_{n} \}$ has no convergent subsequence because
   $$\|Tx_{n}-Tx_{m}\|^{2}=|\lambda_{n}|^{2}+|\lambda_{m}|^{2} \ge 2t^{2},\;\; n \ne m. $$