# Functional analysis question about proving $J(\phi)=||\phi||$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a normed space $X$ and let $Q$ be the quotient map i.e. $Qx=x+M$ for all $x \in X$. Let $M^{\perp}=$ {$ \psi \in X^{*} : \psi(m)=0$ $\forall m \in M$}.

Prove that :

a) $M^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace of $X^{*}$ and hence complete.

b) The map $J : (X/M)^{*} \to M^{\perp} $ given by $J(\phi)(x)= \phi(Qx)$ $\forall x \in X$ is a linear map

c) For $\psi \in M^{\perp}$ , $\phi$ given by $\phi((x+M))=\psi(x)$ is well defined and belongs to $(X/M)^{*}$.

d) ||$J(\phi)$||=||$\phi$|| for every $\phi \in (X/M)^*$ and hence in particular injective.

$\textbf{My Attempt-}$

a) I consider a map $\phi_m :X^{*} \to \mathbb{C}$ which takes $\psi $ to $\psi(m)$. Now if I could prove $\phi_m$ is continuous then $M^{\perp}$ being inverse image of {$0$} must be closed and I am done. But why is it continuous, is the argument correct. And if it is, then how to say it is complete. I have no idea about completeness.

b) Linearity I have checked.

c) I have also checked that $\phi$ is well defined but how to show it belongs in $(X/M)^{*}$, is it because its domain clearly is $(X/M)$ and codomain is also obviously lies inside codomain of $\psi$ which is $\mathbb{C}$. That easy or I am wrong here!

d) About this part I will be highly thankful if somebody could give me a proof, as I am nowhere with this. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Every closed subspace of a complete metric space is complete. Point c) is highly incomplete: you must prove that $\sup_{x +M\neq 0} |\phi(x)|/\|x+M\| < \infty$.

Comment: But $X$ may not be banach here. Why it has to be complete

Comment: Because $X^*$ is complete, since it coincides with $\mathcal{L}(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

Comment: @Siminore and why my $\phi_m$ has to be continuous?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, if you could only do part d) for me as an answer, i will be obliged. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- (a) Let $J : X\rightarrow X^{\star\star}$ be the canonical map defined by
  $$
                        (Jx)(x^{\star})=x^{\star}(x).
  $$
  This is an isometric map. The advantage of this approach is that you can write
  $$
                   M^{\perp}=\{ x^{\star} \in X^{\star} : (Jx)(x^{\star})=0\;\;\; \forall x\in M\}= \bigcap_{x \in M}\mathcal{N}(Jx).
  $$
  The intersection on the right is closed because it is the intersection of closed subspaces; and this is true regardless of whether or not $M$ is closed. Because $X^{\star}$ is complete, then $M^{\perp}$ is also complete.
- (b) You have verified this
- (c) For $\psi \in M^{\perp}$, you are asked to show that $\phi(x+M)=\psi(x)$ defines $\phi \in (X/M)^{\star}$. Yes, $\phi$ is well-defined, but you must also establish continuity. For this, note that
  $$
             |\phi(x+M)|=|\psi(x+m)| \le \|\psi\|_{X^{\star}}\|x+m\|,\;\;\; m \in M.
  $$
  Taking the infimum over all $m \in M$ gives
  $$
                        |\phi(x+M)| \le \|\psi\|_{X^{\star}}\|x+M\|_{X/M}
  $$
- (d) If $\phi \in (X/M)^{\star}$, then $(J\phi)(x) = \phi(x+M)$ defines $J\phi \in M^{\perp}\subset X^{\star}$ with
  $$
       |(J\phi)(x)| = |\phi(x+M)| \le \|\phi\|_{(X/M)^{\star}}\|x+M\|_{X/M}
                    \le \|\phi\|_{(X/M)^{\star}}\|x\|_{X}.
  $$
  Therefore $\|J\phi\|_{X^{\star}}\le \|\phi\|_{(X/M)^{\star}}$. To prove the opposite inequality, use part (c), or repeat the argument: For all $m \in M$,
  $$
      |\phi(x+M)| = |(J\phi)(x)| = |(J\phi)(x+m)| \le \|J\phi\|_{X^{\star}}\|x+m\|
  $$
  Therefore $|\phi(x+M)| \le \|J\phi\|_{X^{\star}}\|x+M\|_{X/M}$, which implies $\|\phi\|_{(X/M)^{\star}}\le \|J\phi\|_{X^{\star}}$.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth : You are welcome.