# Show that both $S$ and $T$ are bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $S$ and $T$ be linear map defined on hilbert space $H$ s.t. $\langle Su,v \rangle=\langle u,Tv\rangle $ $\forall u,v \in H$. Then show that both $S$ and $T$ are bounded.

$\textbf{TRY-}$ If I can show $S$ is bounded than $T$ is bounded but I am unable to show $S$ is bounded. I was working on it but getting nowhere. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I guess, [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Adjoint) says that unbounded operators may have adjoints as well.

Comment: @Ilya But how does that helps me!

Comment: It seems your question reads as: if $S$ and $T$ are linear maps on Hilbert space $H$ such that $T$ is adjoint of $S$, then both $S$ and $T$ are bounded. Since there seem to be adjoints of unbounded operators, I guess the statement is incorrect, but let's wait for a person with more experience in functional analysis.

Comment: @T.A.E. Thanks for this. I got it. Am I correct In this [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040052/find-eigenspectrum-of-t)? Can you tell proper way to prove it.

Comment: I posted a solution there. Take a look. You can show that the operators are closed, and then apply the closed graph theorem.

Comment: @T.A.E. Yes I got it after going through your solution. But I have referred a different question in above comment. Thanks a lot