# Find eigenspectrum of $T^{*}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let {$u_n$} be an orthonormal basis of Hilbert space $H$. Let $T \in B(H)$ s.t. $T(u_n)=u_{n+1}$ for $n \ge 1$. Find eigenspectrum of $T^{*}$.

I have tried to find it taking the corresponding matrix of $T^{*}$ and tried to find out the eigenvalues of $T^{*}$ and I got $[0,1)$. Is this correct?

Comment: If you are working on the complex numbers the eigenspectrum is the open unit ball. Otherwise is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the basis is $\{ u_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Then $T$ is the unilateral shift operator. Note that $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ for all $x \in H$. So the spectrum of $T$ is contained in the closed unit disk, which means that the spectrum of $T^{\star}$ is also contained in the closed unit disk. The adjoint is the backwards shift with $T^{\star}u_{1}=0$ and $T^{\star}u_{n}=u_{n-1}$ for $n > 1$. You can show this directly, starting with
$$
    Tx = T\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x,u_{n})u_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x,u_{n})u_{n+1}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
    (Tx,y) & =(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x,u_{n})u_{n+1},y) \\
           & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x,u_{n})(u_{n+1},y) \\
           & =(x,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(y,u_{n+1})u_{n}) = (x,T^{\star}y)
\end{align}
$$
which implies
$$
                  T^{\star}y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(y,u_{n+1})u_{n}.
$$
This is the backwards shift because $T^{\star}u_1=0$ and $T^{\star}u_{n+1}=u_{n}$ for $n \ge 1$.

Every $\lambda$ for which $|\lambda| < 1$ is an eigenvalue of $T^{\star}$. To find the eigenvector, notice that for $|\lambda| < 1$, the following converges:
$$
                       e_{\lambda}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{n-1}u_{n}
$$
In vector format, $e_{\lambda}=(1,\lambda,\lambda^{2},\lambda^{3},\cdots)$. Because $T^{\star}$ is the left shift,
$$
   T^{\star}e_{\lambda}=(\lambda,\lambda^{2},\lambda^{3},\cdots)
        = \lambda (1,\lambda,\lambda^{2},\cdots) = \lambda e_{\lambda}.
$$
Hence, every $e_{\lambda}$ is an eigenvector of $T^{\star}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. So every $\lambda$ for which $|\lambda| < 1$ is an eigenvalue. And you can see this is the only eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ because $T^{\star}x=\lambda x$ with $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots)$ implies
$$
            (x_2,x_3,x_4,\cdots)=(\lambda x_1,\lambda x_2,\lambda x_3,\cdots),
$$
which gives $x_2=\lambda x_1$, $x_3=\lambda x_2 = \lambda^{2}x_1$, etc.. So this is necessary. But, because this leads to $x\in l^{2}$ iff $|\lambda| < 1$, then we know we've found all of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T^{\star}$. The spectrum of $T^{\star}$ is closed and contained in the closed unit disk. So we know that entire closed unit disk is in the spectrum. However, for $|\lambda|=1$, we know that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue.