# Show $\sigma(T)=\sigma{(\overline{T^{*}})}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $T \in B(H)$ be a bounded operator.  Is $\sigma(T)=\sigma{(\overline{T^{*}})}$ true for $T$?

$\textbf{TRY-}$ I have proved it is true for normal operator but could not do it for bounded operator. Any help please! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $T-\lambda I$ is invertible with inverse $A \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ iff
$$
                     I = (T-\lambda I)A = A(T-\lambda I)
$$
The above holds iff
$$
     I = A^{\star}(T^{\star}-\overline{\lambda}I) = (T^{\star}-\overline{\lambda}I)A^{\star}.
$$

Comment: With your Hint I concluded that statement is true. Am I right?

Comment: Where have you used boundedness of $T$?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth : The existence of the adjoint requires some condition, and boundedness is good enough on a Hilbert space. Then also, for bounded $A$, $T$, $(AT)^{\star}=T^{\star}A^{\star}$, etc. Your conclusion is correct.

Comment: hi @Disintegrating By Parts can you please tell me how to conclude that $\sigma(T^*)=\overline{\sigma(T)}$ in a Hilbert space ? i know that T is invertible iff $T^*$ is and tries to use definition..

Comment: @user726608 : $\lambda\notin\sigma(T) \iff (T-\lambda I)$ is invertible $\iff (T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)$ is invertible $\iff \overline{\lambda}\notin\sigma(T^*)$.

Comment: Hi ,@Disintegrating By Parts thanks but I asked about $\sigma(T^*)=\overline {\sigma(T)}$ (a different equality than the question asked in this post)..

Comment: @user726608 : This is a set equality that follows from what I gave you. What I showed you is this: $(\mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma(T))=\overline{(\mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma(T^*))}$.

Comment: It comes down to set complement, conjugation, and knowing that $T^*-\overline{\lambda}I$ is invertible iff $T-\lambda I$ is invertible. Give it some thought @user726608 .

Comment: @Disintegrating By Parts can you please show how we get that ?

Comment: @user726608 : If $A$ is invertible with inverse $B$, then $AB=BA=I$, which also gives $B^*A^*=A^*B^*=I^*=I$, making $A^*$ invertible with inverse $B^*$.